# How do I add another keyboards into Remix OS (Vietnam, Cambodia, Thailand Keyboards)

Tags: 5.0-lollipop, keyboard, android-emulator, external-keyboard, remix-os

I have a problem which are I cannot add another keyboards namely, Vietnam, Cambodia and Thailand. I cannot change the Keyboard from English language to Vietnam, Cambodia and Thailand languages. 
I have tried Khmer Smart Keyboard, Cambodia Keyboard APK and Phum Keyboard for Cambodia keyboard; 
Keyboard ManMan, Gadgetdoor Thai Keyboard, Thai Gingerbread KB and Thai Pack Without ALM97774503 for Thailand keyboard.

My host OS is Windows 7. I use VM-ware player to run Remix OS and Remix OS is marshmallow.
How do I add another keyboards into Remix OS please?

Kindly please help me out. Any suggestion, I would appreciate it.

Comment: Try RedrawKeyboard, i think it has Cambodian and other languages like those.

Comment: Hi, how to use the redraw keyboard. it has 2 features, namely enable keyboard and activate keyboard. but when i tried to click both of them, nothing happen. please guide me @Geo